# How to add the social media buttons inside the content of an article?

Tags: php

How to add the social media buttons inside the content of an article?

I've inserted many times the social buttons in a webpage, but always outside of the content as a separate div... This time i want to try something more fancy and add them inside the article. See image:

[image]

The social buttons code (just the code without the javascript) is in a php file called social_buttons.php. Something similar to this:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

The content of the article is captured via a php form in a textarea control and insert it in the database. I then output the content from the database and echoed as following:

```
<?php echo $article; ?>
```

So basically, the social_buttons need to go inside the $article...

How do i achieve this?

Comment: I think using div with position solves your problem, for the div that is container for the article style="position:relative" and for social buttons div use style="position:absolute; right:10px; top:100px;" and test it

Comment: @AkamOmer: yeap! it's all about positioning... Thanks

Comment: did you test it? my solution is jut an idea not exact...

Comment: i did and it works... the only thing is if i want to insert the div after the 3 paragraph or whereever i decide, this solution fails... i'm working on another solution that i've research and also works and were i can insert the div anywhere...i will post it once i get it to work